# Is there a way to check if a row is hidden by a filter view in Google Sheets using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My goal is to identify if a row is hidden by a filter view.

As far as I know and as of posting this question, there are currently two methods for checking if a row is hidden or not: [`isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition) and [`isRowHiddenByUser(rowPosition)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyuserrowposition).

`isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)` doesn't work since it

> "Returns whether the given row is hidden by a filter (not a filter
> view)." -- [Method description in Google Apps Script Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition)

Is there a way or even a workaround to achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you share a working copy of your sheet with your current script?

Comment: @JasonE. I'm sorry, I really can't because of an NDA. Also, why do you think it will differ if you see the code? This could still be a valid question without having an underlying code. This is more of a general question I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the hidden row numbers by the filter view using Google Apps Script.

### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, there are no methods for directly retrieving the hidden rows and showing rows by the filter view in Spreadsheet service (`SpreadsheetApp`). And, the method of "isRowHiddenByFilter" of Class Sheet cannot be used for the filter view.

But, fortunately, when Sheets API is used, the filter view can be retrieved and created. In this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using Sheets API. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Retrieve the settings of the filter view (`filterViews`) you want to use.

   - In this case, the method of "spreadsheets.get" can be used.
2. Create new basic filter to the sheet you want to use using the retrieved settings of the filter view.

   - In this case, the method of "spreadsheets.batchUpdate" can be used.
   - In the case of basic filter, the filtered rows can be retrieved. This workaround uses this situation.
3. Retrieve the values of `rowMetadata` of the sheet.

   - In this case, the method of "spreadsheets.get" can be used.
   - At the values of `rowMetadata`, the filtered rows have the property of `"hiddenByFilter": true,`. Using this, you can retrieve the hidden rows and/or the showing rows.
4. Delete the created basic filter.

> **IMPORTANT**: In this flow, when the basic filter is used in the sheet, the basic filter is cleared. Please be careful this. When you test this script, please use the sample Spreadsheet.

### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please manually set the filter view and set the filter view name. This script uses this filter view.

```
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const filterViewName = "sampleFilter1"; // Please set the filter view name.

  // 1. Retrieve the settings of the filter view (`filterViews`) you want to use.
  const res1 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, { ranges: [sheetName] });
  const sheetId = res1.sheets[0].properties.sheetId;
  const filterViews = res1.sheets[0].filterViews.filter(
    (e) => e.title == filterViewName
  );
  if (filterViews.length == 0) {
    throw new Error("Filter view cannot be found.");
  }

  // 2. Create new basic filter to the sheet you want to use using the retrieved settings of the filter view.
  const obj = filterViews[0];
  obj.range.sheetId = sheetId;
  const reqs = [
    { clearBasicFilter: { sheetId: sheetId } },
    {
      setBasicFilter: {
        filter: {
          criteria: obj.criteria,
          filterSpecs: obj.filterSpecs,
          range: obj.range,
          sortSpecs: obj.sortSpecs,
        },
      },
    },
  ];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: reqs }, spreadsheetId);

  // 3. Retrieve the values of `rowMetadata` of the sheet.
  const res2 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, {
    ranges: [sheetName],
    fields: "sheets",
  });
  const values = res2.sheets[0].data[0].rowMetadata.reduce(
    (o, r, i) => {
      if (r.hiddenByFilter && r.hiddenByFilter === true) {
        o.hiddenRows.push(i + 1);
      } else {
        o.showingRows.push(i + 1);
      }
      return o;
    },
    { hiddenRows: [], showingRows: [] }
  );

  // 4. Delete the created basic filter.
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
    { requests: [{ clearBasicFilter: { sheetId: sheetId } }] },
    spreadsheetId
  );

  console.log(values);
}
```

### Result

When above script is used for the following sample Spreadsheet,

#### Before filter view is not set.

[image]

#### After filter view was set.

[image]

#### Result value

From above Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

```
{
  "hiddenRows": [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9],
  "showingRows": [1, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
}
```

- `hiddenRows` is the hidden row numbers.
- `showingRows` is the showingRows row numbers.

### Note:

- This is a workaround using a simple script. So please modify above script for your actual situation.

### References

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)